# Receiving callback with HTML on jQuery post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I want to submit POST data to same (current) page but on callback just receive HTML which I echoed in "if [$_POST]" code block. 
Currently I do return HTML code to that span I click but of the whole page, which I don't want for sure.

I hope you understand what I mean since it is pretty simple and I think my codes would confuse you even more. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. Please show your code, and explain what it's doing wrong.

Comment: Have your php only return the content you want when you want just that specific content.

Comment: you can select out the chunks of html that you want out of the returned html by wrapping the returned html in a div and then doing your selects off that.

Comment: No,I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I think question is:
how to request only part of the page only instead of getting full source in case I use POST to send data needed? 
This can not be resolved correctly on the Javascript side. All you actually need is to check on the server side: is there POST data or not? In case of POST data exists you should form and response with small part of the page only.
Also you actually can to parse full the page's source you just get and find only part you need. But this way you will get performance- and traffic-related issues.
And as conclusion I suggest you to use different URL for getting only one small part: use the same URL with different methods for different purposes is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to exit your script after you sent your response.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['is_ajax'])){?>
    goes content
<?php 
} die;
?>
```

then other content.

OR BETTER WAY

```
    if(
      !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) 
      && 
       strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'
    ) {?>
                goes content  
<?php }  die;?>
```

Comment: I tried:
<?php if (isset($_POST['something'])) { echo "HTML content for that span"; die; } ?>
<html>Whole page here..</html>

It returns the whole page...